# DONE key on android keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, enter, ime

I'm having trouble with done/enter/next key. I'm making android soft keyboard and whenever I try to search for something I can't do that because when I press DONE key the cursor just moves to next row. Here is my code:

XML

```
<Key android:keyLabel="DONE" android:keyWidth="11.11%" android:codes="-1"/>
```

JAVA

```
@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    switch(primaryCode){
        case -1:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
        default:
            char code = (char)primaryCode;
            if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
    }
}
```

Example: If I search for something on Google and I type what I want and when I click DONE key I want it to start the search. Can you please help me with that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of

```
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
```

try

```
ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
```

The action performed should be the one defined on the EditorInfo, which is passed to you on method onStartInputView

To switch between actions, use this:

```
(sEditorInfo.imeOptions & (EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION))
```

Hope this helps.

Code:

```
case -1:

    switch (sEditorInfo.imeOptions & (EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)) {
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
            ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
            break;
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
            ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
            break;
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
            ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
            break;
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND:
            ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND);
            break;
        default:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
    }

    break;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick answer. I'm new to Android so I don't know where should I put this line of code: (sEditorInfo.imeOptions & (EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)) I have onCreateInputView and you said that this line of code should be in onStartInputView. Can you explain it to me what should I put where?

Comment: You must override onStartInputView to get EditorInfo

`public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo info, boolean restarting) {`

Then, on

`case -1:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;`

instead of sending akey event, you should switch for the value of 

`(sEditorInfo.imeOptions & (EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION))`

and for each case, you perform the respective EditorAction (IME_ACTION_GO, IME_ACTION_NEXT, IME_ACTION_SEARCH, ...)

Comment: Ok, i get it, but can you show me the code and than I can see what is going on. I don't know what to do with `(sEditorInfo.imeOptions & (EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION))` . Here is my code: `case -1:
                 1ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
                break;`

Comment: what are the cases for `switch (sEditorInfo.imeOptions & (EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)) {}`

Comment: please, look again to the example. you have it all there.

Comment: OMG, I didn't see that part of answer. Sorry for that. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm getting error every time I press DONE key. It says "Unfortunately, Keyboard has stopped."

Comment: Thank you so much! Wish android had some docs for this, cause you really saved me.

Comment: BTW, anyone coming from kotlin, replace the `&` with `and` and `|` with `or`

Comment: This answer is missing the IME_ACTION_DONE as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo info, boolean restarting) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    switch (info.imeOptions & (EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)) {
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
            ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
            break;
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
            ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
            break;
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
            ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
            break;
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND:
            ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND);
            break;
        default:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
    }
}
@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);
    switch(primaryCode){
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE: // how this case needs to be handled ??
            //ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));

            break;
        default:
            char code = (char)primaryCode;
            if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as well; don't just paste the code